# Using javascript Blob to save data as a CSS file

Tags: javascript, blob

I have the following function to save a file to the browser using `blob`...

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
```

I am passing the following data to it...

```
var filename = "style.css";
var data = CSSFile //CSS string

saveData(data, filename)
```

My `data` is a string of CSS attributes that I want to save as a CSS file. The problem is, when I open the downloaded CSS file, it look like...

```
"html, body {....} ... "
```

Notice it is surrounded by double quotes. I need these removed. I tried the following...

```
CSSFile = CSSFile.substring(0, CSSFile.length - 1);
saveData(data, filename)
```

But all that did was remove the first character inside the double quotes...

```
 "tml,body{...}..."
```

How can I save the string without the double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting quotes in your string because you are running it through JSON.stringify when it is already a string.

Try this instead.

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
```